# git - Commit staged changes to another branch and merge

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-commit, branching-and-merging

I find that frequently, while working on a large feature branch, I make changes to parts of the codebase that really belong on their own branches. I know that I could use `git add -p` to stage the changes I want, commit them, stash the changes I don't want, make a new branch off of master, cherry-pick the commit I made earlier, switch back to the original branch, reset, merge in the feature branch, and pop my changes, but that seems like a lot of work for something that should be easier to do. There should be a way to do this without affecting my work directory, right?

Here's a drawing of what I'm trying to do.

[image: A crude drawing depicting branches]

I'd love to have a command like

```
$ git commit --onto master --as new
```

that would create a `new` branch off `master`, commit the changes there, then merge it into my HEAD branch, all without touching my work directory. Does such a command exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any such command, but you could build your own.  It will be a little bit (or maybe a lot) tricky.  You would need a temporary work-tree for the general case, and in that general case, you would have to stop and let the user fix the merge conflicts.  However, if you want to just declare this particular fully-general case out of bounds, and handle only the merge-conflict-free cases, you can avoid having a separate work-tree, as we will see below.

#### Warning: this is (a) long and (b) all untested

(I'm writing this as a sort of academic exercise, illustrating how Git works and how all its various parts can be plugged together to write *new* Git commands, mostly as shell scripts.)

Remember that when you run `git commit`, Git builds a new commit out of whatever you have in your *index*.  The index is the invisible cache-like data structure that occupies the space between your `HEAD` (or current) commit and your work-tree.

In your drawing, the dashed circle labeled *staged* is the commit that you *will have* after `git commit` turns your index into a tree, then wraps that tree object with a new commit object.  Your work-tree is not used in this process (with one exception having to do with whether someone has run `git commit --only` or `git commit --include`, which construct new temporary index files and then internally use a `git add` to copy from the work-tree into the new temporary index, but let's avoid this particular rathole here).

#### Breakdown of the process of making an ordinary commit

Normally, you don't need to know all of this: the `git commit` command takes care of it all.  And in fact, you could use that command, except for the fact that you don't *want* an ordinary commit, you want a *merge commit*.  So we will need to do things by hand, and/or take some longer and more circuitous route.  Let's start by watching *how* `git commit` would make the new commit it would make, if we just ran `git commit` now.

Note that each commit holds a full and complete snapshot of *all* files.  The dashed circle labeled *staged* would be made into a real commit, which would also automatically update `dev`, by what amounts to the following process.  All error checking has been omitted for clarity.  I assume here that the log message is available in a shell variable, though using `-F file` will also work to take the log message from a file.  We'll break this down a bit after looking at the four commands here, but see also the individual manual pages for each command:

```
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)  # will fail if HEAD is detached
tree=$(git write-tree)                   # will fail if, e.g., index is unmerged
commit=$(git commit-tree -p HEAD -m "$message" $tree)         # can fail
git update-ref -m "commit: $subject" $current_branch $commit  # can fail
```

The `git symbolic-ref` command reads the *name of the current branch* from `HEAD`.  Most Git operations get the *hash ID* of the current *commit* from `HEAD`, but we need the name—in this case, `refs/heads/dev`, as you're on your `dev` branch—for the last step.

The `write-tree` packages up the index as a tree object.  This, in essence, freezes forever the contents of the files that are in the index right now, in the form they have right now.  The resulting top level tree object is suitable for the new commit.

The `commit-tree` creates the commit object that uses this frozen tree.  It needs to know what the *parent* of the new commit is; that's whatever hash ID `HEAD` provides, via `-p HEAD`.  It needs the log message; that's what the `-m` (or `-F`) argument is for.  And, it needs the hash ID of the *tree* object that goes into the commit; that's what `$tree` is for.

(The commit consists of the commit object itself, which `git commit-tree` just wrote, plus the tree object, which `git write-tree` wrote, plus all the blob objects, which are already in the index, along with any sub-trees required to link them all together, which `git write-tree` wrote when it wrote the top level tree.)

This *makes* the commit, but the current branch, `refs/heads/dev`, still names the *old* current commit—the one that *was* current before we just made this new commit.  We must now fix that, so that, while `HEAD` itself still just refers to `refs/heads/dev`, `refs/heads/dev` itself refers to the *new* commit.  This causes the new commit to become the current commit!  The Git command to do this is the last of our four commands, `git update-ref`.  The `-m` argument provides the message to go into our reflog.  The regular `git commit` command uses, as this log message, the string `commit:` followed by the subject (first line, more or less) of our full log message, so we put that into the shell variable `$subject` and use it here.  It also needs to know the new hash ID to stuff into the reference name, which is of course the new commit we just made, `$commit`, from `git commit-tree`.

**That's what a `git commit` right now would do for you**: it would make an ordinary single-parent commit, on branch `dev`, updating the branch name `dev` to point to the newly created commit.  The new commit would, through its tree object, freeze for all time the contents of all files that are in the index right now.  Unfortunately, **that's not what you want.**  What you want is to have Git make a new commit whose type is not an ordinary, single-parent commit, but rather one whose type is a *merge commit:* a commit with two parents.  The *first* parent of this merge commit should be the current (`HEAD`) commit as usual, but the *second* parent of this commit should be a *new* commit made from ... well, here's where it gets tricky.

#### In order to make your new merge commit, you must first make your new *other* commit

To get what you want—the graph pictured on the *right* side of your diagram—we need to make the new commit labeled `new` first.

In order to make this commit, we must construct a snapshot, into an index, of what all the files will look like.  Note that I say here *an* index, rather than *the* index.  We're starting to pick up some of the complications!  (This is the sort of thing that `git commit --only` and `git commit --include` do, too.)

Because Git is built around *snapshots*, not *change-sets*, we must first turn the *current* index into a change-set.  That is, we must diff the current commit against the index, to see which files we're changing here and what we are doing to them:

```
git diff-index --cached -p HEAD
```

The output here is (mostly) the same as that from `git diff --cached`, but this uses a *plumbing command* rather than the *porcelain* (user-configurable) `git diff` front end.  This ensures that the output is in a nice, stable, easy-to-digest format, ready for consumption by other programs, including other Git commands.

Note that this kind of diff compares the tree in `HEAD` to the tree represented by the index / staging-area.  It completely ignores the tree in the work-tree.  That's what we want, because that's what `git commit` would commit: whatever is in the index.  We want whatever is in the index right now, compared to the frozen tree in `HEAD`, in the form of a patch.

This patch is now suitable to be applied to the tree in the commit that is at the tip of branch `master`—the round solid circle labeled `master` on either side in your picture.

In ordinary Git usage, the way we'd apply this patch *to* this tree is to extract the tree—the one associated with the tip of `master`—into the *work-tree*.  But that's something you *don't* want.  Moreover, unless there are unresolveable conflicts while applying this patch, we'd like to not *make* a temporary work-tree at all.

Still, let's explore that a bit first.

#### Using an added work-tree

We could, here, use `git worktree add`, available since Git 2.5.  Due to a fairly nasty little bug, it's wise to avoid keeping these around for more than two weeks unless you have a pretty up-to-date Git, but our plan here is probably to use it for no more than a few *seconds*, so that would be OK.  The bug is fixed in Git 2.15.

An added work-tree comes with its own `HEAD` and its own index.  It also provides all the room we need to do a full `git apply -3` and allow merge conflicts.  So we could:

```
path=$(mktemp -d)
git worktree add -b new $path master
```

to create a new branch named `new`, pointing to the same commit as `master`, storing the added work-tree in `$path`, which is a new temporary directory.

Having created this new branch in its private work-tree, we now need only apply the patch we just extracted:

```
# this bit of clumsiness is due to the subshell problem
# (there are multiple workarounds, this one is simple)
status_file=$(mktemp)
echo fail > $status_file

git diff-index --cached -p --full-index HEAD | 
    (cd $path
    if git apply -3; then
        git commit -m "$message" && echo success > $status_file
    fi
    )

read status < $status_file; rm $status_file

case $status in
success)
    new_commit=$(cd $path && git rev-parse HEAD)
    git worktree remove $path
    ... finish up the job (see below) ...
    ;;
fail)
    echo "oops, sorry, things went wrong"
    echo "the mess is left in $path"
    echo "you will need to finish the merge and finish the job"
    ;;
esac
```

The `git apply` command applies the patch.  The `-3` flag directs it to use a three-way merge if necessary.  I also added `--full-index` to the `git diff` operation so that we get full hash IDs in the patch, which makes `git apply`'s job easier, though technically it's not necessary in modern Git (which ensures that the index line is sufficient—with old version of Git, the `--full-index` is required in large repositories).

Note that we *could* use `git cherry-pick` here, rather than `git diff... | git apply`.  Technically that would actually be superior as it would handle some file rename cases that the diff-and-apply technique can't handle.  But we're looking at doing this without adding a work-tree, and when we do that, we won't be able to use `git cherry-pick`.

#### Using a temporary index instead of an added work-tree

What we can do now is begin directing Git to use a temporary index, using the special environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE`.  There are a few peculiarities here: whatever path is in `$GIT_INDEX_FILE`, Git demands that the file either *not exist* or *have the form of a valid index*.  So we can do it like this:

```
tf=$(mktemp)
rm $tf
```

This creates a temporary file with a unique name, then removes it.  Now `$tf` is suitable for use as the `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, because it names a file that *doesn't exist*.

We can put the temporary file in the `.git` directory as well:

```
tf=$(TMPDIR=$(git rev-parse --git-dir) mktemp)
```

but I *think* that's unnecessary here.

Or, we can borrow the method `git stash` uses:

```
TMPindex=${GIT_INDEX_FILE-"$(git rev-parse --git-path index)"}.stash.$$
```

but replace `stash` with the name of our own script, whatever that is—and I'm using `$tf` below rather than `TMPindex`.  Note that `git rev-parse --git-path index` itself is new in Git 2.13, so if your Git is older, don't use this method.

Now that we have a temporary index, we can instruct various Git commands to use that *instead of* the regular index.

To build our new commit, we must:

1. Extract the tree from the tip of `master`, into that index
2. Apply our patch *to* that index, without touching any work-tree.  This may fail!
3. Use that index to create a new commit, just as we used the regular index to create a new commit in the illustration of what happens with a normal commit.  Once we have done all that, we will be ready to create a *merge* commit.

Ignoring the failure cases, we now need [**edit**: per comments, I've dropped `--full-index` and `-3` below; `--cached` mode cannot do a three way merge]:

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$tf git read-tree refs/heads/master
git diff-index --cached -p HEAD |
    GIT_INDEX_FILE=$tf git apply --cached
tree=(GIT_INDEX_FILE=$tf git write-tree)
new_commit=$(git commit-tree -p refs/heads/master -m "$message_for_new" $tree)
git update-ref -m "$subect_for_new" refs/heads/new $new_commit
```

The `read-tree` command extracts the tree from the given commit—in this case, the tip of `master`—into the index file, which we redirect to our temporary index.

The `diff-index` command is what we have already seen.  It uses the real index.

The `apply` command this time has `--cached` added, so it applies the changes *only* to the index, <s>doing a three-way merge if required</s>.  We use the temporary index for this.  (We lose the ability to do a proper three way merge, so there are more failure possibilities than before!)

The `write-tree` command writes the temporary index to a tree, which is now ready to go into a commit, and the `commit-tree` command turns this tree into a commit.  We saw all this before—the difference this time is that the parent of the new commit is the tip of branch `master` (`refs/heads/master`), and of course we have a different commit message.  The `update-ref` creates or updates the branch named `new`—rather rudely *losing* any previous branch named `new`, so it would probably be wise to be careful with this, or perhaps not bother with a branch *name* at all (i.e., drop the `git update-ref` step entirely).

#### Making a merge commit

Now that we have our new commit, whose hash ID we have in the variable `$new_commit`, we're ready to go back to our original four-command sequence that creates a new commit on `dev` and then updates `dev`.  To create this new commit as a *merge commit*, rather than as an ordinary commit, we need only give it the two parents.

Hence, again ignoring all error handling, the command sequence is:

```
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)
tree=$(git write-tree)
commit=$(git commit-tree -p HEAD -p $new_commit -m "$message" $tree)
git update-ref -m "commit: $subject" $current_branch $commit
```

#### Putting it all together

Here's the whole thing as a totally untested, somewhat dangerous, no-error-handling-provided script:

```
#! /bin/sh

current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)
other_branch=refs/heads/master

message_for_new="magic new commit from script

I am a commit made by applying a diff.  I was made automatically by a script.
This is a terrible commit message, indicating that the script needs improvement."

message="new merge from script

I am a merge commit made by pretend-merging a magic commit made on ${other_branch#refs/heads/},
but actually using the staged files on ${current_branch#refs/heads/}.
This is a terrible commit message, indicating that the script needs improvement."

subject=$(printf '%s\n' "$message" | sed -n -e 1p)

# create a temporary index, and be sure to clean it up on exit
tf=$(mktemp); rm $tf; trap "rm -f $tf" 0 1 2 3 15

# create new ordinary commit via patch from current index
# this commit has $other_branch as its (single) parent
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$tf git read-tree $other_branch
git diff-index --cached -p HEAD |
    GIT_INDEX_FILE=$tf git apply --cached
tree=$(GIT_INDEX_FILE=$tf git write-tree)
new_commit=$(git commit-tree -p $other_branch -m "$message_for_new" $tree)

# create new merge commit on current branch, using this index and
# the commit just created above
tree=$(git write-tree)
commit=$(git commit-tree -p HEAD -p $new_commit -m "$message" $tree)
git update-ref -m "commit: $subject" $current_branch $commit
```

Comment: I just ran through this manually, and it worked great except for that git apply doesn't let you combine `--cached` and `-3`. Thank you for the brilliant answer!

Comment: Interesting, but that actually makes sense: a proper three way merge requires a work-tree and `--cached` refuses to touch the work-tree.